# Unauthorized Mirosoft Graph request? Calendar.Read

Tags: php, web, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to execute the following Microsoft Graph request:

```
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-04-17T12:13:36.933Z&enddatetime=2020-04-24T12:13:36.933Z';
$data = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'client_id' => '<myclientid>', 'client_secret' => '<myclientsecret>', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/myapp/request.php', 'code' => '<myauthorisationcode>');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer <myaccesstoken>",
        'header'  => "Host: login.microsoftonline.com",
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

Actually I should get information about my calendar now. But I receive the following warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-04-17T12:13:36.933Z&enddatetime=2020-04-24T12:13:36.933Z): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\request.php on line 16
>   bool(false)

In Azure I have added the following 3 API permissions: Calendars.Read, User.Read, User.Read.All.

[my API Authorizations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbU4G.png)

Does anyone know why my request has not been accepted?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check the access token whether it has required permission first.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron What exactly do you mean? I use `scope=offline_access` in the link. And in Microsoft Azue I have activated all necessary API permissions.

Comment: I mean decode your token to have a look it has permission you are looking for.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I was able to decode my access token. This worked without any problems. For which claims do I have to check the value?

Comment: `"roles": [
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite"
  ]` it should either have these permission.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks for your help! The following permissions are defined in the token: Calendars.Read Mail.Read offline_access User.Read User.Read.All

So the permissions are correct?

Comment: Yes its correct.

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: No, unfortunately I still get the same error message.

Comment: I am noob at `php` so I cannot provide you example. But can assist with C# if you can convert.